# If pmf is given how do I find estimator using moment method?

Tags: estimation, expected-value

So, the pmf for $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ is given as : $f(x) = \theta x^{\theta - 1}, \ \ if x \in ]0,1[ \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise.}$

So I try to find first moment: $E[x] = \int^1_0 x\theta x^{\theta -1} dx =x^{\theta +1} - \theta \int^1_0 x ^{\theta-1} dx = x^{\theta + 1} - 1  $

And $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_1^n x_i$. Then from there $x^{\theta+1} = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_1^n x_i + 1 \Rightarrow  \theta = \ln(\frac{1}{n} \Sigma_1^n x_i + 1  - x)  - 1$

This is confusing and most probably incorrect, so where is my mistake and how should I solve this problem?

$$\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\hat{\theta}+1} = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_1^n x_i \\ \hat{\theta} = \frac{\hat{\theta}+1}{n}\Sigma^1_0 x_i = \frac{1}{n} \left(\hat{\theta} \Sigma^1_0 x_i + \Sigma^1_0 x_i\right) \\ \hat{\theta} - \frac{\hat{\theta}}{n}\Sigma^1_0 x_i = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_0^1 x_i \\ \hat{\theta} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\Sigma^1_0 x_i   \right) = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma^1_0 x_i \\ \hat{\theta} = \frac{\bar{x}}{1-\bar{x}}$$

Comment: Are you sure about the square brackets in ]0,1[ ?

Comment: @Ale: That is how some (frenchmen) write $(0,1)$. Strange folk ...

Comment: lol, thank you for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this would be a beta distribution such as the one in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with $\alpha = \theta$ and $\beta = 1$.

First, consider that $E[x] = \int_0^1x\theta x^{\theta-1} dx= \theta \int_0^1x^\theta dx=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1} x^{\theta+1}|_0^1 = \frac{\theta}{\theta+1}$.

Then you can find $\hat{\theta}$ using the method of moments such that $\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\hat{\theta}+1} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: it is given like I said, where $x \in (0,1)$, how to proceed in that case?  Also, how can I express $\hat{\theta}$ from the expression that you wrote?

Comment: The solution I gave would be the same for $x \in (0,1)$. From there, you can easily get $\hat\theta$ in a couple of steps.

Comment: Is my solution now correct?

Comment: Yes! In your original question the error was when computing $E[x]$, this is where I corrected you. (And I guess on the support of $x$.)

Comment: Is this pmf from some known distribution? Also, is it possible for this distribution to apply the moment method in program R?

Comment: Yes, it is a beta distribution with a fixed parameter: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution in your case $\alpha = \theta$ and $\beta = 1$. If this solved your problem you can accept my answer.

Comment: Do you conclude it by the definition of $E[X]$ for this distribution or is there a different way?

Comment: I say that it's a beta distribution given its pdf.

Comment: No, I mean the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Sorry.

Comment: The same. The pdf (and not pmf, since it's continuous) defines the random variable.  And I assume you made a typo and it should be $x \in [0,1]$. From that I conclude that it's a beta distribution with $\beta = 1$. The $E[x]$ follows.